# Is it possible to extend CI_Controller / CI_Model from stdClass

Tags: php, codeigniter, stdclass

Im initialising a class using `stdClass` like:

```
$Upload = new stdClass;
```

1. Is it possible to extend controller / model for this class?
2. Is it possible to have a construct for this class?

I wanted to have a controller or model for upload if possible.
The reason I want is this is that because I am having this in a `php` file that I created and there are function in that file. And depending on the function I want to create different `stdClass` for its required purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdClass` is a predefined `class` built into PHP. It is essentially an empty object. It is also used to typecasting to an object. So no, it cannot have a constructor.

The CodeIgniter classes `CI_Controller` and `CI_Model` are already defined, so no you cannot create 'controller' or 'model' by extending `stdClass`. But perhaps I misunderstand your question.

You can use `stdClass` anywhere you want in a model or controller and easily add properties to it.

```
// create an instance of stdClass
$Upload = new stdClass;
// add a "name" property
$Upload->name = "foo";
// add a "title" property
$Upload->title = "Bar";

echo $Upload->name;  //outputs foo
```

The above might be easier to create by typecasting an array

```
$upload = (object) ['name'=>'foo', 'title'=>'bar'];
echo $upload->name;  //outputs foo
```

Comment: i guess what i wanted is not possible then. Clarify is great happy coding